# The study references too many candles in history. How to avoid it?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the following code. My goal is to find a specific length value for Bollinger Bands so I scan Bollinger Bands in a `for` cycle.

```
LengthBasically = 50 
LengthEventually = LengthBasically * 5 

AdaptiveBollingerLength() =>
    StaDevCalculations = array.new<float>(0)
    for Length = LengthBasically to LengthEventually
        StaDev = ta.stdev(hlc3, Length)
        array.push(StaDevCalculations, ta.highest(StaDev, Length) / ta.lowest(StaDev, Length))
    length_SmallBollinger = LengthBasically + array.indexof(StaDevCalculations, array.min(StaDevCalculations))
    length_SmallBollinger

var int length_SmallBollinger = LengthBasically
if ta.change(close)
    length_SmallBollinger := AdaptiveBollingerLength()
```

So, it practically works but TradingView says:

Which I don't understand because the maximum length value for this Bollinger Bands investigation is 250 (50 × 5, in this case).

[image]

BUT if I remove `max_bars_back = 1000` from the `indicator()` declaration then the error message is this:

[image]

Comment: I had no issues with the script when I attached it to the OANDA:EURUSD 1H chart. Which chart did you use?

Comment: GBPUSD. And it truly depends on some unknown circumstances. Anyways, I should prepare the script against it somehow, knowing what happens… :/ 

Comment: Ookaay, it's interesting. I have a complex custom indicator mash-up with this new feature with in. But if I separate the code into another script, making it standalone, then no issue. So the problem is not in the code above. I have a long, long troubleshooting process ahead.

Answer (score 0):

For debug, use the `barIsVisible()` function from [this library](https://www.tradingview.com/script/j7vCseM2-VisibleChart/)

Some like this:

```
LengthBasically = 50 
LengthEventually = LengthBasically * 5 

AdaptiveBollingerLength() =>
    StaDevCalculations = array.new<float>(0)
    for Length = LengthBasically to LengthEventually
        StaDev = ta.stdev(hlc3, Length)
        array.push(StaDevCalculations, ta.highest(StaDev, Length) / ta.lowest(StaDev, Length))
    length_SmallBollinger = LengthBasically + array.indexof(StaDevCalculations, array.min(StaDevCalculations))
    length_SmallBollinger

var int length_SmallBollinger = LengthBasically


barIsVisible() =>
    bool _barIsVisible = time >= chart.left_visible_bar_time and time <= chart.right_visible_bar_time
if barIsVisible() and ta.change(close)
    length_SmallBollinger := AdaptiveBollingerLength()
```

Comment: Thank you. I ran into a bit of a plumbing emergency here, I'll try your code a little later. :) 